# How to make my 'sessions' to never expire?

Tags: zend-framework, session, cookies

I'm using Zend Framework.

I want to do something similar to SO, when you are not a registered user, you keep your account as long as you remove all your cookies.

I know that session <> cookies, however what will be the best way to do that?

By the way, I'm using memcached because I plan to share sessions between frontend.

Is there any recommendations about this? because memcached data are volatile.

May I need to store them in a database instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution could be calling `Zend_Session::rememberMe()` in each request, once you have checked that the user is authenticated.

Hope that helps,

Comment: I tried that, whilst it extends the session experiration, it doesn't prevent the session to expire when the browser is closed, by the way what about memcached?

Comment: It works for me after closing the browser. Just in case... Did you call it after starting the session? According to Zend_Session documentation, it should be called before the session starts:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.global_session_management.html#zend.session.global_session_management.rememberme
Sorry, I can't answer to the memcached part of your question, I don't use it.

Comment: Some additional suggestions can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489807/zend-framework-session-expires-prematurely . You might also need to set the PHP `session.gc_maxlifetime` parameter appropriately.