# How can i keep users logged in when they return?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication

I am building a web platform, and it would be nice if I could keep users logged in on a semi-permanent basis as facebook / google etc do.

I am working in ASP.NET VB, and have created a basic login system (not using forms auth) whereby a user submits their username and password, it checks against the database (SQL Server 2012), if they match, the user is granted access (session("loggedin") = true) and their details are all stored as session variables to lower the amount of database calls during their site use.

What is the simplest, secure way to achieve this?

Comment: [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx)??

Comment: Been asked and answered.  Do some research. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290837/how-do-i-keep-a-user-logged-in-for-2-weeks

Comment: I knew it would have been but i couldnt find anything...

Hmm no - looking at that, its an entirely different context, ive created a simple login system, not using anything pre-built.

Comment: Cookies as the answers suggested.

Comment: You will probably need to use cookies.

Comment: @DarkcatStudios: Check the "most upvoted" answer in the linked question, not the "accepted" answer. That would be the method to use. Cookie holds a cryptographically unique hash, which matches the same hash as stored in your DB.

Comment: Ah yes! - I had thought something like that was the way forwards.